# Scala, Play: IntelliJ cannot serialize Map[String, List[String]]

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have an object of type Map[String, List[String]]. Should be easy to serialize. Indeed if I run the console in the project dir I can do:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._    

scala> Json.toJson(Map("ab" -> List("yo", "yo2", "yo3"), "cd" -> List("hi", "hi1", "hi2")))
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"ab":["yo","yo2","yo3"],"cd":["hi","hi1","hi2"]}
```

Which is fine. But IntelliJ (Ultimate) complains that

```
No Json serializer found for type scala.collection.Map[String,List[String]]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

even though the same import play.api.libs.json._ is there. I am quite puzzled. Any hint?

Comment: Is this a warning or an error? I'll try to invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ first.

Comment: @RobertUdah it's a proper error :/ and invalidating the cache hasn't helped..

Comment: From the log, it appears it expects an implicit value for the Writes.

Comment: maybe try putting imports and code in single code block `{ import ...; Json.toJson ... }` or in object

Comment: Which version of Play you use? Seems like for older versions there were such issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467689/scala-to-json-in-play-framework-2-1
Probably in your IntelliJ project you use a different version of Play which resolves to different version of json lib than those you import in scala console?

Comment: You guys won't believe it: it was a hidden mismatch between scala.collection.Map and scala.Predef.Map (== scala.collection.immutable.Map) (:facepalm). Thanks for all your valuable help.

Comment: Haha! We all have those days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite lame: the issue was a (hidden) mismatch between scala.collection.Map and scala.Predef.Map (== scala.collection.immutable.Map). I wish it would have been more visible.