# How to convert Map to Json in Scala

Tags: json, scala

My map is as below :

```
Map(
Columbus Herzog -> 
 Map(
 0 -> Map(source -> Las Cruces Crawford Arpt (LRU), amount -> 5000.0, points -> 500, date_time -> Sat Feb 13 02:18:14 IST 2016, class -> First, destination -> San Luis Arpt (IPI)), 
 1 -> Map(source -> Las Cruces Crawford Arpt (LRU), amount -> 5000.0, points -> 500, date_time -> Fri Jul 22 01:52:19 IST 2016, class -> First, destination -> San Luis Arpt (IPI)), 
 2 -> Map(source -> Las Cruces Crawford Arpt (LRU), amount -> 5000.0, points -> 500, date_time -> Wed Jan 06 06:24:50 IST 2016, class -> First, destination -> San Luis Arpt (IPI)), 
 3 -> Map(source -> Las Cruces Crawford Arpt (LRU), amount -> 5000.0, points -> 500, date_time -> Tue May 17 17:12:16 IST 2016, class -> First, destination -> San Luis Arpt (IPI))
 )
)
```

I want JSON array like as below :

```
{"Columbus Herzog":
[{"source":"Las Cruces Crawford Arpt (LRU)","amount":"5000.0","points":"500","date_time":"Sat Feb 13 02:18:14 IST 2016","class":"First","destination":"San Luis Arpt (IPI)"}],
[{"source":"Las Cruces Crawford Arpt (LRU)","amount":"5000.0","points":"500","date_time":"Fri Jul 22 01:52:19 IST 2016","class":"First","destination":"San Luis Arpt (IPI)"}],
[{"source":"Las Cruces Crawford Arpt (LRU)","amount":"5000.0","points":"500","date_time":"Wed Jan 06 06:24:50 IST 2016","class":"First","destination":"San Luis Arpt (IPI)"}],
[{"source":"Las Cruces Crawford Arpt (LRU)","amount":"5000.0","points":"500","date_time":"Tue May 17 17:12:16 IST 2016","class":"First","destination":"San Luis Arpt (IPI)"}]
}
```

Please advice on it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467689/scala-to-json-in-play-framework-2-1) might help you understand more about JSON

Answer (score 1):

What about `net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats`

```
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._
import net.liftweb.json.Printer.{compact,pretty}

object LiftJsonWithCollections extends App {

    val json = List(1, 2, 3)
    println(compact(JsonAST.render(json)))

    val map = Map("1" -> "one", "2" -> "two")
    println(compact(JsonAST.render(map)))
}
```

and output:

```
[1,2,3]
{"1":"one","2":"two"}
```

Just replace content of `Map` to own.

Comment: I have tried with this but "decompose" give the error like not found.

Comment: @ChetanNakum, this example is using [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json) external library. Just make sure you add it to your build.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for reply but when I'm try to add the maven then I got the error like "error while loading JsonAST, Scala signature JsonAST has wrong version  expected: 5.0  found: 4.1 in JsonAST.class"

I have user below maven:
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
 <artifactId>lift-json</artifactId>
 <version>2.0-M5</version>
</dependency>

Comment: My map is like below :
val map = Map("Jerrod Lindgren" -> Map(0 -> Map("source" -> "Clinton Municipal (CWI)", "amount" -> 3000.0, "points" -> 300, "date_time" -> "Fri Oct 16 11:06:03 IST 2015", "class" -> "Business", "destination" -> "Nanjing Arpt (NKG)")))

Comment: @Chetan Nakum You will have a nested maps. What is wrong?

Comment: Please try with my map in above example.
It's not working.

Comment: @Chetan Nakum i will try it later

Comment: Ok sure and let me know If anything.
Thank you